# Table is not forming correctly in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, datatable

**EDIT 1 -**

Plnkr to demonstrate the problem - http://plnkr.co/edit/qQn2K3JtSNoPXs9vI7CK?p=preview

> ---------------- ORIGINAL CODE AND PROBLEM ----------------

I am using [angular datatable](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome) to generate table view.

My very simple **controller** code is as follows -

```
function tableTestCtrl ($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, localStorageService) {
    console.log('From Table');
    var tbData = localStorageService.get('tabledata') || {};
    var dd = new Array();
    dd = [{"Name": "Tiger Nixon", "Age": "61"},{"Name": "Garrett Winters","Age": "63"}];   
    //$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource(dd);
    $scope.dtOptions = dd;
    console.log($scope.dtOptions);
                $scope.dtColumns = [
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Name').withTitle('Name'),
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Age').withTitle('Age')
            ];
}
```

My **view** code -

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-controller="tableTestCtrl">
    <div class="table-responsive" ng-if="dtOptions">
        <table datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Following is the result I am getting(no error in console) -

[image: Result]

If I remove comment from the line -

```
//$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource(dd);
```

It is alerting following error -

> DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Invalid JSON
>   response. For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/1

Please let me know what I am doing **wrong** here.

Comment: i think you json is not formated correctly . try http://jsonlint.com/ to validate you json ..

Comment: @KishoreSahas It passes, its very simple array of objects `[{"Name": "Tiger Nixon", "Age": "61"},{"Name": "Garrett Winters","Age": "63"}]`

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) for better understanding ?

Comment: @KishoreSahas Check this out http://plnkr.co/edit/qQn2K3JtSNoPXs9vI7CK?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
.withOption('data', dd);
```

You can also set other Options using the DTOptionsBuilder. You tried to built the complete Datatables Options using JSON, while you only ment to set the "data" attribute.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0zHD0RHA2h22sgrUyO6v)